# Error expression

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005

I am working on Visual C++. Can you please help in this syntax .

```
  class CVisionSystem
  {
    public:
CVisionSystem();
 ~CVisionSystem(void);


int Init();


    private:

 PvDevice device;
// PvStream object
      PvStream stream;
// Buffer

  CustomPipeline *pipeline;

// GEV Parameters
PvGenParameterArray *deviceParams;
    PvGenInteger *parTLLocked;

 };

int CVisionSystem::Init()
 {
 deviceParams = device.GetGenParameters();    
 parTLLocked = dynamic_cast<PvGenInteger *>( deviceParams->Get( "TLParamsLocked" ) );

 }
```

deviceParms gets valid value, however parTLlocked gets NULL value that leads to an error : "error expression cannot be evaluated, _vfptr CX0030 and mthis CX0076.

What can be the problem of ParTLLocked ?

Comment: `deviceParams->Get( "TLParamsLocked" )` can't be casted to `PvGenInteger *`

Comment: It would help a lot if you said what library you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that `deviceParams->Get( "TLParamsLocked" )` returns a type that can not be dynamic casted to `PvGenInteger *`. The return type should be a pointer to either a subclass or a parent class of `PvGenInteger`(or possibly the same class) for this dynamic_cast to return non-null value.

Comment: so, what can be the solution  ? and please check the edited question once again

Comment: Please add class heirarchy at least so that I can answer your question.

Comment: @Nabeel I am sorry but you did not. I need to see what does `deviceParams->Get` return and what class does `PvGenInteger` inherit. Also include what does the return type of `deviceParams->Get` return.

Answer (score 1):

If `dynamic_cast` can't cast to the target type it returns a null value. You should check for this.

For dynamic cast to succeed the object being casted must have the target class type somewhere in it's inheritance tree. That is the target type must be the actual type of the object at runtime or one of it's parent classes. This means you can only downcast objects that are actually of the target type.

Comment: it would be good if you explain in easier words. i am sorry, i didnot get your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
PvGenParameterArray *lDeviceParams = d->lDevice.GetGenParameters();    
lTLLocked = dynamic_cast<PvGenInteger *>( lDeviceParams->Get( "TLParamsLocked" ) );
```